# Block is synchronised only when using unrelated object in Scala

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, parallel-processing

I have a function `getUniqueId` that tries to return a unique ID on every call.

```
private var uidCount = 0L

def getUniqueId() = uidCount.synchronized {
  uidCount = uidCount + 1
  uidCount
}
```

It's definition is synchronized on the `Long` variable `uidCount`.

We are calling this function using another function `startThread`.

```
def startThread() = {
  val t = new Thread {
    override def run() = {
      val uids = for (i <- 0 until 10) yield getUniqueId()
      println(uids)
    }
  }
  t.start
}
```

So, for every function call, we should ideally see 10 unique IDs printed on our console.

We call for IDs using multiple threads as shown below:
`startThread(); startThread(); startThread()`

But I get output with duplicate IDs:
Output:

```
Vector(7, 11, 13, 16, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
Vector(2, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21, 23)
Vector(1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20)
```

Here we can see that 8 and 12 are duplicated.

Similarly, If I synchronize `getUniqueId()` on a random object of Class `AnyRef`.
I.e I change the definition to:

```
private var uidCount = 0L
private var x = new AnyRef
def getUniqueId() = x.synchronized {
  uidCount = uidCount + 1
  uidCount
}
```

Then all of a sudden getUniqueId is atomic. The output is always similar to:

```
Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
Vector(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
Vector(21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
```

i.e Without duplicates.

Can someone explain Why can't I use `uidCount` to make `getUniqueId` atomic?

Comment: Synchronization does not happen on _variables_, it happens on _objects_, and `Long` is a value type.

Comment: I assume ```Long``` is a wrapper class or at least something similar. Because if what you say is true, then it shouldn't have the method ```synchronized``` defined, but it does.

Comment: So you are using **Scala** one of the best languages to manage concurrency with a lot of concurrent frameworks with multiple goodies and then you want to use basic threading synchronisation like this was **Java 5**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uidCount` is a primitive variable that is changing all the time.

Every time you call `getUniqueId`, a new wrapper is created around the primitive value. Synchronizing on a new object that is created anew every time you enter the method body does not make any sense: the intrinsic lock associated to this object will always be acquired exactly once, then it will be immediately released, and the wrapper object will be discarded.